# SVN two factor authentication

Tags: svn, two-factor-authentication

I need to implement a solution to secure SVN access using two factor authentication. Ideally I'd like to use Google Authenticator along with Basic auth. How would I proceed with implementing such a solution?

I'm considering developing a web proxy page that must first be authenticated to through a browser and once authenticated, follow on SVN commands would pass through. Does this seem feasible or is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure but I'd check if there's an Apache authentication solution that will do the job.

Comment: Is this proxy going to be accessed on WAN or LAN?

Comment: I was able to solve this with setting up an Apache integration. I'll provide further details for others once I get all of the steps documented.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These directions will work for Ubuntu 12.04. I should note that these directions were pulled from several different sources across the web. There was no definitive guide for getting this setup.

First, install updates and C/C++ compiler if it doesn't exist already:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Install Subversion and Apache:

```
$ sudo apt-get install subversion
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-svn apache2
```

Enable SSL:

```
$ sudo a2enmod ssl
$ sudo vi /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

In the open file change "NameVirtualHost *" to "NameVirtualHost *:443"

Generate Certificate:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ssl-cert
$ sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl
$ sudo /usr/sbin/make-ssl-cert /usr/share/ssl-cert/ssleay.cnf /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
```

Accept the localhost value for the cert by hitting enter

Create Virtual Host:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/svnserver
$ sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/svnserver
```

In the open file change VirtualHost * to VirtualHost *:443

Add the following below the ServerAdmin tag in the opened file and then save and close:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
SSLProtocol all
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
```

Enable the site:

```
$ sudo a2ensite svnserver
$ sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add the following line to the open file, save, and close:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Restart Apache:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Adding a repository to SVN:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/svn
$ REPOS=myFirstRepo
$ sudo svnadmin create /var/svn/$REPOS
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/svn/$REPOS
$ sudo chmod -R g+ws /var/svn/$REPOS
```

Repeat everything but mkdir /var/svn to create additional repositories

**Google Authenticator**

Install PAM and download and build Google Authenticator:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev
$ cd ~
$ sudo wget http://google-authenticator.googlecode.com/files/libpam-google-authenticator-1.0-source.tar.bz2
$ sudo tar -jxf libpam-google*
$ cd libpam-google*
$ sudo make install
```

**Google Auth Apache Module**

Download and install Google Auth Apache Module:

```
$ wget https://google-authenticator-apache-module.googlecode.com/files/GoogleAuthApache.src.r10.bz2
$ sudo tar -jxf GoogleAuthApache.src.r10.bz2 
$ cd google-authenticator*
$ sudo apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev
$ sudo vi Makefile
```

in the opened file, change line 1 to:

```
APXS=apxs2
```

then change line 7 to point to the location to install and save and close the file:

```
install: all
     sudo cp .libs/mod_authn_google.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/
```

Replace mod_authn_google.c with the code from r21 on the project site here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator-apache-module/source/detail?r=21
(this is when true two-factor auth was added)

```
$ sudo make install
```

Setup two factor auth in Apache:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/
$ sudo mkdir two-factor 
$ sudo vi httpd.conf
```

Add the following line the opened file, save, and close:

```
Loadmodule authn_google_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_google.so

$ sudo vi ports.conf
```

In the open file change  to

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/mods-available
$ sudo vi dav_svn.conf
```

In the open file add the text below, save, and close:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn 
    SVNParentPath /var/svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Google Authenticator Code"
    AuthBasicProvider "google_authenticator"
    Require valid-user
    GoogleAuthUserPath /etc/apache2/two-factor/
    GoogleAuthCookieLife 3600
    GoogleAuthEntryWindow 2
    SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

Restart Apache:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

At this point SVN, Apache, and Google Authenticator are configured. Now users can be added.

**Adding Users**

First, users need to be added as a system user so they show up appropriately in the Google Auth client

```
$ sudo adduser firstName.lastName --force-badname
$ sudo su - firstName.LastName
# google-authenticator
```

Google Authenticator will ask several questions. These should be reviewed based on the environment this is being deployed to.

Copy the URL that is printed after answering the first question - this is the URL for the QR code and used to add the key to your Google Auth client

```
# exit
$ cd /etc/apache2/two-factor
$ sudo cp /home/firstName.lastName/.google_authenticator firstName.lastName
$ sudo chown -R :www-data /etc/apache2/two-factor/  
$ sudo chmod g+r firstName.lastName
$ sudo vi firstName.lastName
```

Modify the opened file to include a line similar to the below line, save, and close:

```
" PASSWORD=myTestPassword
```

Everything should now be configured. To login, browse to the URL and use the username, and password + 6 character Google Authenticator code.